# Java: get a string back into HashMap

Tags: arrays, hash, hashmap, minecraft

I have this String

```
{Enchantment[minecraft:sharpness, DAMAGE_ALL]=2, Enchantment[minecraft:unbreaking, DURABILITY]=1}
```

and I want to get this back into an Hashmap

```
Map<Enchantment, Intiger> map = new HashMap<>();
```

but how?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create a custom parser.

A good starting point would maybe be some kind of a regex pattern matcher to extract individual terms. And then it should be fairly trivial to parse each match and add the resulting key and value into a hashmap.

Not sure exactly what your use case is, but you might be better off trying to serialise the enchanment values rather than converting to a string and then parsing it.

Comment: Okey, but how? So the String can contains more or less entrys. How to do it?